# spread rows into columns based upon presence.

Tags: r

given the following data:

```
location = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
day = c("Mon","Mon","Mon","Tue", "Tue")
type = c("road", "scan", "fly", "road", "fly")

dat <- data.frame(location,day, type) 


location day    type
   A       Mon  road
   A       Mon  scan
   A       Mon  fly
   B       Tue  road
   B       Tue  fly
```

I need a way to wrangle this so that it looks like this

```
location day road scan fly
     A    Mon   1   1   1
     B    Tue   1   0   1
```

maybe with spread?

Comment: Use `reshape2::dcast(dat, location + day ~ type, fun = length)`

Comment: Related [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: If you're dealing with large data, I recommend using data.table, it will provide significant speed improvements.

Comment: alternative:  `dat %>% mutate(n = 1) %>% tidyr::spread(type,n, fill = 0)`

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html is a really useful read as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tiudyverse`.  Get the frequency grouped by 'location', 'day', 'type' with `count` and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  count(location, day, type) %>% 
  spread(type, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  location day     fly  road  scan
#  <fct>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        Mon       1     1     1
#2 B        Tue       1     1     0
```

---

A `base R` option with `aggregate` and `reshape`

```
reshape(aggregate(val ~ ., transform(dat, val = 1), length), 
    idvar = c('location', 'day'), direction = 'wide', timevar = 'type')
```